Бот, который разрешает скачивания файлов из канала, если человек подписан на этот канал
Не могу найти информацию по написанию бота, который будет разрешать скачивать из канала файлы только тем, кто подписан на этот канал. Планирую писать на aiogram3. Подскажите, как перехватывать изменения в канале (подписан /не подписан пользователь, когда нажимают на скачивание файла)? Какую информацию можно почитать на эту тему? Заранее благодарю.

файлы скачиваются через бота?
